# Get latitude & longitude from address geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, arcgis, geopandas

I have a csv of about 100 million logs. Where one of the column is address and I am trying to get latitude and longitude of the address. I want to try something like mentioned in the Solution , But the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252863/geocoding-using-geopy-and-python) given is `arcGIS` and that is a commercial tool. I did try `google API` that has limit of 2000 entries only.

What is next best alternative to get address's Lat & Long into the large dataset.

Input: The column `Site` is the address from the City Paris

```
start_time,stop_time,duration,input_octets,output_octets,os,browser,device,langue,site
2016-08-27T16:15:00+05:30,2016-08-27T16:28:00+05:30,721.0,69979.0,48638.0,iOS,CFNetwork,iOS-Device,zh_CN,NULL
2016-08-27T16:16:00+05:30,2016-08-27T16:30:00+05:30,835.0,2528858.0,247541.0,iOS,Mobile Safari UIWebView,iPhone,en_GB,Berges de Seine Rive Gauche - Gros Caillou
2016-08-27T16:16:00+05:30,2016-08-27T16:47:00+05:30,1805.0,133303549.0,4304680.0,Android,Android,Samsung GT-N7100,fr_FR,Centre d'Accueil Kellermann
2016-08-27T16:17:00+05:30,,2702.0,32499482.0,7396904.0,Other,Apache-HttpClient,Other,NULL,Bibliothèque Saint Fargeau
2016-08-27T16:17:00+05:30,2016-08-27T17:07:00+05:30,2966.0,39208187.0,1856761.0,iOS,Mobile Safari UIWebView,iPad,fr_FR,NULL
2016-08-27T16:18:00+05:30,,2400.0,1505716.0,342726.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
2016-08-27T16:18:00+05:30,,302.0,3424123.0,208827.0,Android,Chrome Mobile,Samsung SGH-I337M,fr_CA,Square Jean Xxiii
2016-08-27T16:19:00+05:30,,1500.0,35035181.0,1913667.0,iOS,Mobile Safari UIWebView,iPhone,fr_FR,Parc Monceau 1 (Entrée)
2016-08-27T16:19:00+05:30,,6301.0,9227174.0,5681273.0,Mac OS X,AppleMail,Other,fr_FR,Bibliothèque Parmentier
```

The address with NULL can be neglected and also can be removed from the output.

The output should have following columns

```
start_time,stop_time,duration,input_octets,output_octets,os,browser,device,langue,site, latitude, longitude
```

Appreciate all the help, Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @InaS I did mention that I worked with Google Api and that has limitation,  next best suitable solution I found was with arcgis and that is commercial package.  Hence i have no proper way to put up a code,  if I put the Google API code then the whole question will go in different direction.. I have tried that already few days ago in another question..

Comment: Just to clarify, you're mainly asking for a way to get lat/lon coordinates for a large data set and less about how to manipulate the data with pandas/python. Is that right?

Comment: @pshep I am open to manipulation and also getting lat lon

Comment: I would suggest to use geopy with the Open Street Map Nominatim geocoder: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Thank you for the suggestion .. Do u think you can help me with some code please ..

Comment: This question would *still* be a lot better if it could be reduced to a MRE like @IanS recommended ... if the OP has time to do so please consider it, for the benefit of SO in general.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import csv
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

#if your sites are located in France only you can use the country_bias parameters to restrict search
geolocator = Nominatim(country_bias="France")

with open('c:/temp/input.csv', 'rb') as csvinput:
    with open('c:/temp/output.csv', 'wb') as csvoutput:
       output_fieldnames = ['Site', 'Address_found', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
       writer = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, delimiter=';', fieldnames=output_fieldnames)
       writer.writeheader()
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)
       for row in reader:
            site = row['site']
            if site != "NULL":
                try:
                    location = geolocator.geocode(site)
                    address = location.address
                    latitude = location.latitude
                    longitude = location.longitude
                except:
                    address = 'Not found'
                    latitude = 'N/A'
                    longitude = 'N/A'
            else:
                address = 'N/A'
                latitude = 'N/A'
                longitude = 'N/A'

            #here is the writing section
            output_row = {}
            output_row['Site'] = row['site']
            output_row['Address_found'] = address.encode("utf-8")
            output_row['Latitude'] = latitude
            output_row['Longitude'] = longitude
            writer.writerow(output_row)
```

Comment: You can have different information from the geolocalized location, for instance the type of building, etc...

Comment: The geocoder might give you wrong locations because the site info in your input csv is not accurate. If you can have at least the city, the results would be better

Comment: The locations are from Paris city distributed city wide, And yes this has given the output with one row which has no latitude and longitude, :(

Comment: This just stops with first row `NULL,Not found,N/A,N/A`

Comment: Ok let me try with your sample, I'll come back with something

Comment: Here it goes! ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is now baked directly into Geopandas: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/geocoding.html

Taken directly from their docs:

```
import geodatasets

boros = geopandas.read_file(geodatasets.get_path("nybb"))

boros.BoroName
Out[3]: 
0    Staten Island
1           Queens
2         Brooklyn
3        Manhattan
4            Bronx
Name: BoroName, dtype: object

boro_locations = geopandas.tools.geocode(boros.BoroName)

boro_locations
Out[5]: 
                     geometry                                           address
0  POINT (-74.14960 40.58346)  Staten Island, New York, New York, United States
1  POINT (-73.82831 40.71351)         Queens, New York, New York, United States
2  POINT (-73.94972 40.65260)       Brooklyn, New York, New York, United States
3  POINT (-73.95989 40.78962)      Manhattan, New York, New York, United States
4  POINT (-73.87859 40.84665)      The Bronx, New York, New York, United States
```